# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

такая вот ошибка, нашёл немного информации про вайт листы, но не понял, как исправить с помощью них эту проблему. 
Контроллер

```
    class ItemsController < ApplicationController
def create
       @item=Item.create(params[:item])
       if @item.errors.empty?
        redirect_to item_path(@item)
       else 
        render "new"
       end
  end
```

Изменил на:

```
def create
    @item=Item.create(smth)
       if @item.errors.empty?
        redirect_to item_path(@item)
       else 
        render "new"
       end
  end

private 
def smth
    params.require(:item).permit(:price,:name,:description,:weight)
    end
```

Но чего-то не хватает, т.к. отображается новая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У тебя в `after_create` передается блок, в котором нет переменной `category`

Answer (score 1):

Надо исправить колбеки на

```
#app/models/item.rb
after_create ->(item) { item.category.inc(:items_count, 1) }
after_destroy ->(item) { item.category.inc(:items_count, -1) }
```